# SDO_GEOM.RELATE with EQUAL mask returns false for same WKT

Tags: oracle-spatial, sdo-geometry, tolerance

I am trying to compare two geometries from two different tables and find all the different with the specified tolerance. 
I'm using `WHERE sdo_geom.relate(gs.shape, 'mask=EQUAL',p.shape,0.002) = 'FALSE';`

I noticed that for some of them sdo_relate returns false even if they seems to be identical.

Both tables contain geometries in EPSG:3857.

For example:

```
    select 
    sdo_geom.relate(
    sdo_geometry('LINESTRING (2376748.542 6790002.073, 2376748.5422 6790002.0732, 2375510.7897 6789311.011, 2375377.3433 6789269.7993, 2375369.493 6789299.2359, 2375369.493 6789299.2359, 2374729.7321 6789099.0644, 2373931.0136 6788745.8239, 2373768.1298 6788694.7999, 2373768.13 6788694.8)',3857),
    'mask=EQUAL',
    sdo_geometry('LINESTRING (2376748.542 6790002.073, 2376748.5422 6790002.0732, 2375510.7897 6789311.011, 2375377.3433 6789269.7993, 2375369.493 6789299.2359, 2375369.493 6789299.2359, 2374729.7321 6789099.0644, 2373931.0136 6788745.8239, 2373768.1298 6788694.7999, 2373768.13 6788694.8)',3857)
    )
    from dual;
```

returns false. This is the same WKT linestring. SDO_EQUAL also returns false.

What is wrong? How to compare linestrings? Why it returns false?

For:

```
select sdo_geom.relate(sdo_geometry('LINESTRING (2376748.542 6790002.073, 2376748.5422 6790002.0732)',3857),
'mask=EQUAL',
sdo_geometry('LINESTRING (2376748.542 6790002.073, 2376748.5422 6790002.0732)',3857))    from dual;
```

sdo_geom.relate returns 'MASK=EQUAL'